# Error: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: angular

My problem is error with message: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

app.module.ts

```
 @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    UsersComponent,
    BackButtonComponent,
    BooksComponent,
    NewBookComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

new-user.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="entityForm" *ngIf="entityForm">
</form>
```

new-user.component.ts

```
entity: User = new User();
entityForm: FormGroup;
```

Comment: I don't see the `NewUserComponent` in the NgModule declarations. Do you have it declared in other module?

Comment: No, I don't have.

Comment: Then you just need to add the `NewUserComponent`  to the declarations array and the problem should be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your new-user component to the NgModule declarations